# Stopping a running handler

Tags: android, timer, android-handler

I have implemented a handler that allows the user to start an event that repeats every 5 seconds using the taskbar menu. What is the best method to use that would also allow the user to stop the event from the taskbar menu?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{ 
  @Override
  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch(item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menuitem_tracklogOn:
            final Handler handler = new Handler();
            Timer t = new Timer();
            t.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                public void run() {
                    handler.post(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            //DO SOME ACTIONS HERE , THIS ACTIONS WILL WILL EXECUTE AFTER 5 SECONDS...
                            handler.postDelayed(this, 5000);//repeat every n-milliseconds
                        }
                    });
                }
            }, 0);//start after n-milliseconds
            return true;

       case R.id.menuitem_tracklogOff:
       //stops running event from R.id.menuitem_tracklogOn
       return true;
```

Solution:

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
Timer t = new Timer();
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch(item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menuitem_tracklogOn:
            t.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                public void run() {
                    handler.post(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            //DO SOME ACTIONS HERE , THIS ACTIONS WILL WILL EXECUTE AFTER 5 SECONDS...
                            handler.postDelayed(this, 5000);//repeat every n-milliseconds
                        }
                    });
                }
            }, 2000);//start after n-milliseconds
            return true;
        case R.id.menuitem_tracklogOff:
            t.cancel();
            handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
            return true;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the best method to use that would also allow the user to stop
>   the event from the taskbar menu?

To Stop `Handler` on `menuitem_tracklogOff` click:

**1.** Cancel `Timer` by calling `timer.cancel()`

**2.** Call `removeCallbacksAndMessages` to remove  all callbacks and messages:

```
handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
```

To access both `Timer` and `Handler` object's outside first `case` declare other outside onOptionsItemSelected method or before `switch-case` block.

Comment: @ρяσѕρєя-k- I've posted your implemented suggestion above...what am I missing? Thanks!

Comment: @portsample: Move both `final Handler handler = new Handler();Timer t = new Timer();` lines outside `onOptionsItemSelected` method

Answer (score 0):

you need to call `timer.cancel()` to cancel your timer.

**public void cancel ()** `// Added in API level 1`

> > Cancels the Timer and all scheduled tasks. If there is a currently running task it is not affected. No more tasks may be scheduled on this Timer. Subsequent calls do nothing.